# Excel VBA Remove Add-In Reference, Close Add-In and Remove From VBA Project

Tags: vba, excel, office-addins

My overall setup is quite involved, so here is my attempt to pin-point the precise part that I'm stuck on.

For whatever it's worth, I will have much respect for whoever can figure this out. I think that the solution requires an esoteric understanding of Excel Add-Ins.

**The Background:**

Here is the relevant universe of files that I am dealing with:

- Filepath_2\UI_2.xlsm
- Filepath_1\CI_1.xlsm
- Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam
- Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm
- Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam

Filepath_2\UI_2.xlsm is the file that is running the VBA to accomplish the desired file operations on/in the other four aforementioned files.

Filepath_1\CI_1.xlsm contains a reference to Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam.

My goal is to...

- Copy Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam to Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam
- Copy Filepath_1\CI_1.xlsm to Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm
- Open Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam
- Open Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm
- Remove, from Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm, the reference to Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam
- Set, in Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm, a reference to Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam
- ... handle business in Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm ...
- Close and delete Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm and Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam

... and, I am able to accomplish all of the above save for one minor snafu:

*The VBA project for Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam is opened upon opening Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm and I cannot figure out any way to close it.*

**The Question:**

**What is the required VBA code to close the *VBA project* for Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam?**

It is worth mentioning that my current inability to close that VBA project is not adversely affecting anything for the time being, so this is really a matter of control and process cleanliness for the longer term. I simply do not want a stray VBA project remaining open.

I can be somewhat flexible about the order of file operations that I mentioned above, as long as it culminates in the last three steps of it:

- Set, in Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm, a reference to Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam
- ... handle business in Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm ...
- Close and delete Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm and Filepath_2\AI_2.xlam

Just one pre-emptive note to save everyone's time: Please do not suggest changes to the current suite of filepaths as the desired solution cannot interfere with the rest of what needs to be done. This file setup is part of a much larger situation that handles business in secondary copies of master files, after which the secondary copies must be closed and deleted.

This is my first question on Stack Overflow. I've attempted to make it self-contained as well as be free of actual VBA code since I don't think that someone who knows the solution I've asked for needs my own code to provide the few lines of code that most likely comprises the solution.

If you think you can help me out but need more information or some actual code, please let me know. Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks for your comments so far. Allow me to clarify further, and I think that this really gets to the crux of the matter. I've also edited my original question to correct some minor inaccuracies.

I earlier misstated one of the steps above as:

Close Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam

I don't attempt to do this anywhere.

Once I open Filepath_2\CI_2.xlsm, it has a reference to and shows the VBA project for Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam; **the problem is that Excel does not, at any point, recognize Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam as an open file**.

In fact, even if I open Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam by its mere self (without opening up any files that reference it), Excel does not recognize it as an open file, although it opens up the VBA project for the file. By 'recognize', I mean that if I use a For Each loop to cycle through the open add-ins (or open workbooks), Filepath_1\AI_1.xlam never shows up.

What I'm trying to do seems like it should be quite doable, and yet I just cannot find any way of doing it that doesn't leave that stray VBA project open...

Comment: This is not an uncommon problem.  From a while back, but maybe check : http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/11/google-desktop/   If you don't have google desktop then try disabling other excel add-ins and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Trey, please see my edit above. Tim, I don't have Google Desktop. Disabling other add-ins doesn't fix the problem. Also, the issue isn't duplicate VBA projects because the problem remains the same even with only one instance of the add-in (and its related VBA project) running. Any other suggestions for me to try?